# Wordpress suggest with key value pair in admin

Tags: php, autocomplete, wordpress

I have a meta box in which there is a text box that grabs the list of custom post type's title. So far its working fine but the problem is that i don't find a way to implement key/value autocomplete using wordpress built-in suggest plugin. Here is my code

```
/**
 * Return list of artists for autocomplete. .
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 */
public function list_artists() {
    // This only send the post titles not the id
    foreach($result as $k => $v) {
       echo $v . "\n";
    }

    // This doesn't work and sends the whole text as json string 
    $results = array(1 => 'Raheel', 2 => 'Zain', 3 => 'Vicky');
    echo json_encode($results);
    die();
  }

/**
 * Provide a dashboard view for the plugin
 *
 * This file is used to markup the public-facing aspects of the plugin.
 *
 * @link       http://example.com
 * @since      1.0.0
 *
 * @package    Songs_Cloud
 * @subpackage Songs_Cloud/admin/partials
 */

function show_album_meta_box() { ?>
    <label for="artist">Artist</label>
    <input type="text" id="artist" name="artist">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($) {
        $("#artist").suggest(ajaxurl + "?action=sc_list_artists", { delay: 500, minchars: 2 });
        });
    </script>
<?php }
```

I am not willing to use dropdown because there can be 1000s for artists and it won't look good in the admin section.

Is there any possibility to achieve this using suggest plugin or any other approach that i can use ?

Answer (score 0):

I think i should utilize [Select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)

That way i will just bind the dropdown dynamically and load the select2 plugin so that it give a nice interface to the admin section rather the long dropdown list.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 is it fine now ?